# grep unique results but show full line containing the match

Tags: grep, regular-expression, filter

I'd like to filter an input like this

```
foo 2022-11-11
foo 2022-12-11
something else
bar 2022-12-07
```

to obtain

```
foo 2022-11-11
bar 2022-12-07
```

I'm starting with `grep -oP "^[A-z]{3}" | sort -u` but of course this will not print the full line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to take only from first column to first column (`-k 1,1`) into consideration:

```
grep -E '^[[:alpha:]]{3} ' | sort -k 1,1 -u
```

Output:

```
bar 2022-12-07
foo 2022-11-11
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining the `k` option. But using the manual for sort, after 15 minutes, I got it figured out to adapt this to my actual usecase.

Comment: I have expanded the answer a bit to clarify the notation used with the comma.